# Merging List after particular element

Tags: python, list, for-loop, merge

I wanted to merge 2 lists together (`ListA`, `ListB`). But the catch is, after a certain element within the `ListA`.

The user enters after which element `ListB` should be merged with `listA`.

For example;

```
ListA = [2,1,0]
ListB = [4,5,6]
```

User Enters **1**.

Output:

```
new_list = [2, 4, 5, 6, 1, 0]
```

Now I was thinking of using a `for loop`, but because of my limited knowledge in `for loops` I don't know how I can make the loop to stop after a certain amount of loops.

Comment: "because of my limited knowledge in For Loops I dont know how I can make the loop to stop after a certain amount of Loops": Not that this is the best way to solve the problem, but if you want to do it this way, the answer is `break`. For example, `for i, value in enumerate(ListA):` then `if i == certain_index: break`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is actually really easy with slice assignment, as explained in the tutorial section on [Lists](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#lists):

```
ListA = [2,1,0]
ListB = [4,5,6]

# make a copy -- I'm assuming you don't want to modify ListA in the process.
new_list = ListA[:]
# insert ListB at a particular location.  I've arbitrarily chosen `1`
# basically this says to take the empty section of the list
# starting just before index 1 and ending just before index 1 and replace it
# with the contents of ListB
new_list[1:1] = ListB
# Check the output to make sure it worked.
print(new_list)  # [2, 4, 5, 6, 1, 0]
```

Comment: could you explain what is happening in here

Comment: @Ali: The official tutorial explains it nicely; I added a link to mgilson's answer.

Comment: Oh very nice... Thanks for the great explanation !! And further explanation of " new_list[1:1] = ListB " .. This has cleared many things for me... And today I learnt some thing new !!!!

Comment: so just to clear it up some more... U are saying that it takes the empty space between element 1 and element 2 and fills it up with ListB?

Comment: @Ali: That's a pretty reasonable way to look at it. But remember your 0-based numbering. It's filling in the empty space right _before_ element 1 (that is, the second element), not _after_.

Answer (score 0):

```
ListA = [2,1,0]
ListB = [4,5,6]
a=[]
def merg(i):
 for i in range(i):
  a.append(ListA[i])
 for j in ListB:
  a.append(j)
 a.append(ListA[i+1])
 return a

print merg(2)
```

DEMO:

```
[2, 1, 4, 5, 6, 0]
```

Comment: I don't think this does what he wants for any case except `i==1`. He wants all of the elements of `a` up to `i`, then all of the elements of `b`, then all of the elements of `a` after `i`. This gives him just the `i`th element first, and puts all the rest at the end.

Comment: did you run the code ? please run it first ! i do and work well its obviously in the code !

Comment: I just did… and it does exactly what I said. For example, with `merg(2)`, you don't get `[2, 1, 4, 5, 6, 0]`, you get `[0, 4, 5, 6, 2, 1]`. In fact, it doesn't even give the OP's desired input for `merg(1)`. He wants `[2, 4, 5, 6, 1, 0]`, you give him `[1, 4, 5, 6, 2, 0]`.

Comment: i read the question again you right ! i had a wrong understand of the code! i edit the code ! correctly !

Comment: If this is not a valid answer to the question, please remove the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way you can do this without any mutating operations:

```
new_list = a[:i] + b + a[i:]
```

To see it in practice:

```
>>> a = [2, 1, 0]
>>> b = [4, 5, 6]
>>> i = 1
>>> new_list = a[:i] + b + a[i:]
>>> new_list
[2, 4, 5, 6, 1, 0]
```

If you don't understand any piece, you can break it down:

```
>>> a[:i]
[2]
>>> a[i:]
[1, 0]
>>> # etc.
```

So, why would you want to do this without mutating operations? Lots of possible reasons:

- Code that doesn't mutate values is easier to reason about. It's exactly like a mathematical function; you don't have to think about the order in which things happen or the state at each step. And you can usually decompose it into simpler pieces, exactly as I did above, if you don't understand it.
- Often you don't actually *want* to mutate anything. In this case, we don't have to make a copy of `a` in advance, because we're not going to modify it.
- It can be more readable, or even more novice-friendly. In this case, you still have to understand slicing, but not slice assignment.
- It's often shorter. This is a one-liner instead of a two-liner.
- It's often more efficient. This avoids copying the entire list and then shifting most of the elements to the right.

But something it's less readable, or more verbose, or less efficient. So, it's worth knowing both ways of doing things, so you can decide which is appropriate on a case by case basis.